# Use Json file for d3.js-graph

Tags: json, d3.js

I'am new in d3.js and want to use the line-chart example:
[line-chart-example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245)
with a external json file, which is located in the same folder like the index.html.

When I change the source to .json I only get a blank page as result. How do I have to change the section to use the json data?

```
    d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(d) {
  d.date = parseTime(d.date);
  d.close = +d.close;
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
```

Comment: Are you not confused that you tried to load json file with `d3.tsv` method? You have to change the load method to `d3.json` in this case - https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#json

Comment: That's what I mean. The change to d3.json("file.json". function(data) { ... does not work.

Comment: Oh, I incorrect understand you. What the structure of your `json` file? Do you change some other code from the example?

Comment: No, the code and the data structure is the same. First I just want to change the data source from the external csv file to an external .json file.

Comment: If you put `console.log('data => ', data)` before `if (error) throw error;` what does it show?

Comment: The result is just a blank page in the Browser.

Comment: Yes, but if you check this `console.log` you can ensure if the data was loaded successful.

Comment: How can I check this? Browser -> analyse -> console? At this point I get a syntax error. 


`d3.json("data.json", function(d) {
  d.date = parseTime(d.date);
  d.close = +d.close;
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
   console.log('data => ', data) if (error) throw error;`

Comment: `GET http://localhost/mike/data.json 404 (Not Found)
send @ d3.v4.min.js:2
get @ d3.v4.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ d3.v4.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ index.html:29
`

Comment: `index.html:30 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'date' of null
    at index.html:30
    at Object.<anonymous> (d3.v4.min.js:2)
    at p.call (d3.v4.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.e (d3.v4.min.js:2)
(anonymous) @ index.html:30
(anonymous) @ d3.v4.min.js:2
call @ d3.v4.min.js:2
e @ d3.v4.min.js:2
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
send @ d3.v4.min.js:2
get @ d3.v4.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ d3.v4.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ index.html:29`

Comment: I changed the filename. Now I have no more errors in the browser console, but only the blank page ...

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have ideas what the problem is.

Comment: Should it work in general, if just the source file is changed to json and the rest code is still the same ?


`d3.json("data.json", function(d) {
  d.date = parseTime(d.date);
  d.close = +d.close;
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;`

Comment: @MikhailShabrikov the problem here is just the row function: `d3.tsv` accepts it, but not `d3.json`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is simple: `d3.json` does **not** accept a row function. It has to be just:

> d3.json(url[, callback])

Given your code:

```
d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(d) {
            d.date = parseTime(d.date);
            d.close = +d.close;
            return d;
        }, function(error, data) {
            if (error) throw error;
```

The "JSON" version of it has to be:

```
d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;
```

So, move the row function...

```
function(d) {
    d.date = parseTime(d.date);
    d.close = +d.close;
    return d;
},
```

... to a `forEach` loop, **inside** the callback.